# Fixed Timetable DB Design

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, sqlite

I want to let my users specify which hours / days they want to be contacted, I though of creating a fixed timetable with the 7 days of the week and let the user specify which hours he has free.

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how I would store that info in the database, can anyone help me with a good table design for this situation?

Comment: Do you really need hour-level resolution? Without knowing more about your exact problem, I would be tempted to have a "preferred contact time" field with a few simple choices like "morning" "afternoon" or "evening"

Comment: @Ken: That may also be an option, I'll take that into account. Thanks for your input. =)

Comment: @Ken: I just realized that I need to provide a day-level resolution, a user may want to be contacted in the morning except at the weekends for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `Day` table contains list of days (Sun, Mon, Tue..), you can also use enumerated field instead.
- The `Period` table contains list of available (hourly) periods, or you could also use part of a day.

[image: contacttime_model_01]

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote @Vainstah; where you see "redundant normalization", I see pre-loaded look-up tables. Where you need to sort-out "overlaps" and duplicate entries "with application logic" in your solution (see below), I see a problem which should not exists in the first place.

Comment: Nothing personal, but both our models capture the same semantics. You've just created a over-the-top data model. In order for these tables to be useful I need to query Day - Contact and Period. That is an academic view of data-modelling not a practical view. Your sollution also requires -- the same -- logic to prevent overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I assume dates are not involved. If dates are involved, remove day and change the time type to date-time types.

So you need entries that look like this·

person_id - day(int 0-7) - time_low - time_high.

Thats all you should need to represent the data. Availability is represented by the ranges between time_low and time_high.

You will need application logic to merge overlaps and resolve overlaps. It should not be too hard.